# How to display all posts under main category and its subcategories?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom php/mysql blog. In single post page, I have a sidebar where I am displaying categories. I want to display number of posts those belong to a main category and its subcategories in brackets as we usually see in WordPress. For now I have

```
Music
Pop
Nature
Lakes
Sea
```

I want to achieve

```
Music (5)
Pop (3)
Nature (8)
Lakes (2)
Sea (4)
```

As you see Music category has 5 posts under it and Pop has 3. But it doesn't mean there are 8 posts in reality. There are actually only 5 posts because Pop is subcategory of main category Music. 2 posts are directly under the main category Music while 3 posts are falling in its subcategory Pop. Thus 2 + 3 = 5.

The categories table looks as (Note that it has nth level of subcategories):

[image]

The posts table looks as (Note that a particular post can have its only one category parent i.e. a post can not have its multiple parents)

[image]

My code to fetch categories and their subcategories is

```
public function get_category_hierarchy(&$output, $parent_url, $parent = 0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` = " . $parent . " ORDER BY `category_name`";
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);                    

    // Removing trailing slash
    $parent_url = rtrim($parent_url, "/");

    if(is_array($rows))
    {
        foreach($rows as $row) :
            $url = $parent_url . "/" . $row->category_url;
            $output.= "<li><a href='" . $url . "'>" . $row->category_name . "</a></li>";
            if($row->category_id != $parent)
            {
                $this->get_category_hierarchy($output, $url, $row->category_id);
            }
        endforeach;
    }
    return $output;     
}
```

On sidebar, I am displaying these categories by following code:

```
$output = '';
// Create post object
$post_obj = new Post();
echo $post_obj->get_category_hierarchy($output, SITE_URL . 'category');
```

Now I'm wondering what code need to be add for fetching number of posts (post counts) that fall under a main category and subsequently its sub-sub-categories? Though I tried to fetch them but the result didn't come accurate.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I modified function get_category_hierarchy() by doing following amendment:

```
foreach($rows as $row) :
    $url = $parent_url . "/" . $row->category_url;

    // Build database query
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total_posts' FROM `tb_posts` WHERE `post_parent` = " . $row->category_id . " GROUP BY `post_parent`";

    // Execute database query
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);

    $output[] = "<li><a href='" . $url . "'>" . $row->category_name . " (" . $rows[0]->total_posts . ")</a></li>";
```

But oops! It is giving me following result:

```
Music (2)
Pop (3)
Nature (2)
Lakes (2)
Sea (4)
```

Obviously, the parent category is having total number of post which are directly associated to it and not to its children. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The approach that I could think of :

- Do a group by on the posts table on the `post_parent`.
- From that form an associative array with the index as `category_id` and pair value as `post_count`.

  Ex. $category_post_counts = array("4" => 5, "5" =>
  10)
- Now run a `foreach` loop for all the category ids and fetch its
  corresponding parent.
- Update the post count by using the indexes.

  Suppose for category id 4(pop) there were 5 posts and in music there
  were 10 posts. Now in the loop if the category parent is anything
  else apart from 0 then update the post count in the array.

  Ex.
  `$category_post_counts["<category_parent_id>"] =
  $category_post_counts["<category_parent_id>"] +
  $category_post_counts["<category_child_id>"]`

This way your end result
   will be an associative array with the category ids and all the post
   counts.

**Pseudo Code**

```
//exctracting all the data
$rows = execute_this_query("SELECT COUNT(post_id) AS `post_count`, `post_parent` FROM `posts` GROUP BY `post_parent`");

//forming the associative array
foreach ($rows as $value) {
    $associative_array[value["post_parent"]] = $value["post_count"]; 
}

$data = execute_this_query("SELECT `category_id`,`category_parent` FROM `categories` WHERE `category_parent` <> 0");

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $associative_array[$value["category_parent"]] += $associative_array[$value["category_id"]]; 
}


//Your final associative array has the exact category_id and net post count as you want.
```

Comment: Can you please suggest your idea in context to my given code?

Comment: ok but can you please check my edited code above? where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try the code that I have written. Your code uses a different approach. You have to just replace the execute_this_query with your sql execute and and connection statements.

Comment: Ok I reconfigured your code to work in my situation. It worked great! I have now an associative array with exact id and net post counts. But as you saw my code, I am doing a recursive function to get category hierarchy, so I need to fit these net post counts corresponding to category id in my code so that i don't loose category hierarchy URL structure.

Comment: Sorry, I unaccepted this answer because it failed to count the posts correctly that belong to parent category indirectly. I wrote a much better and simpler solution to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

First you can populate an associative array for the quantity in each category like: `category_id => post_qty`.

After that, you can use the function bellow to calculate for every category and its children:

```
function count_posts($category_id, $cache) {
    $sum = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` = " . $category_id;
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);        

    foreach ($rows as $child) {
        $sum += count_posts($child->category_id, $cache);
    }
    $sum += $cache[$category_id];
    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: What modification I need to do in my function `get_category_hierarchy()`? I couldn't follow your concept.

Comment: The code I posted has a variable called `sum`, where I sum the posts from a category and its children. Your logic already go through all the categories, but you don't sum the post count.

Comment: Your approach will only allow the sum if you print the post count after your printed their children.

Comment: Oh it has confused me a bit! So do i not need any extra mysql query to count number of posts falling under category and its children?

Comment: Initially I thought i will have to add another mysql query to count total posts in my loop `foreach($rows as $row) :`

Comment: The way I proposed you would have first a SQL which would count the posts from every category, without verifying their children. All this resultset you would attribute to the `$cache` variable.

Comment: You can add, but that approach would decrease the speed of your page. Caching all this resultset beforehand you make it faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103869/discussion-between-user5307298-and-thyago-stall).